# Display the result based on selecting multiple checkboxes using s:checkboxlist in struts2

Tags: struts2, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist as the following:

```
<s:checkboxlist list="books" name="checked" theme="simple" cssStyle="vertical"                      
listKey="code" listValue="description" >    </s:checkboxlist> 
<s:submit value="submit" name="submit"/>
```

I have checkboxes such as academics, fiction, cooking recipes etc. i.e., there are multiple checkboxes from which I can select more than one option. Say for eg., I select fiction and academics, then all the books under fiction and academics should be displayed. If I choose only fiction, then books under the fiction category only has to be displayed. I would like to have a submit button, which when clicked lists all the books based on the selected categories.

When I tried working with onchange funtion inside checkboxlist (the second code as you can see below), it does not work for multiple selections i.e., as soon as I check a single checkbox(e.g.,fiction), the page refreshes automatically before I could check other checkboxes and displays only the books under that particular category(i.e.,fiction). So, the following does not allow me to check multiple checkboxes. Is there any other way I could achieve this?

```
<s:checkboxlist list="books" name="checked" theme="simple" cssStyle="vertical"                      
listKey="code" listValue="description" onchange="searchBook(this)" >    </s:checkboxlist> 


function searchBook(book){
var bookValue   = book.value;
document.getElementById("book").value = bookValue;     
document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Pravin, I have edited and elaborated as you requested. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Book should be selected based on `academics, fiction, cooking recipes` then why you put `onchange` on `books checkbox` and is there onchange event on `academics, fiction, cooking recipes` checkbokes and if you call same function for these checkboes that is `searchBook(book)` then there might be your problem as you submitting the page `document.forms[0].submit();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <s:checkboxlist list="books" name="checked" theme="simple" cssStyle="vertical"  
listKey="code" listValue="description" onchange="searchBook(this)" >    </s:checkboxlist>
```

you can use `onchange` or `onclick`

```
var lastVal = ""; // globale variable
    function searchFunction(){
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checked');
        var vals = "";
        for (var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
          if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
          {
          vals += ","+checkboxes[i].value;
          }
        }
        if (vals) vals = vals.substring(1);
        if(vals != "" && lastVal != vals){
            lastVal = vals;
            document.getElementById("book").value = vals;     
            document.forms[0].submit();
        }

    }
```

Comment: hi @Pravin, thank you. I tried the above code. The result is displayed like that of an AND condition. i.e., Suppose I check fiction and academics, the output is 'none' because it is probably looking for individual books that contains both these categories. Rather, I want the result to contain all the books under the fiction category as well as all the books under the academics category which is like an 'OR' condition.

Comment: I got the result now.. made a few changes in the backend and got the result now! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hi @Pravin, I have another question. is there any way where you can retain the values of the checked checkbox even after the page refreshes(i.e.,when the page refreshes to give the output after document.forms[0].submit())?

Comment: Can you explain me how to do that @Pravin as I am not well aware of this? Please provide an example